# Hang a process

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a (more or less) easy way to force the process of a windows application to hang, and not respond? Or is this entirely dependent on the application/process in question?

**Edit:** What I wanted to try is this: The application in question has a web GUI, and several running processes in the background. There was a report that when one of these processes crashed, the web GUI stopped responding. I would like to try and reproduce that, but I realize it might not be that easy.

Comment: Do you mean you want to force another application to hang? I.e. you'd want to open Notepad.exe and then crash it from your application?

Answer (score 4):

If you can get a handle to a thread in the application, you may be able to call [`SuspendThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686345(VS.85).aspx) which will bring that thread to a screeching halt.

(Note that my answer assumes you want to make another application hang. There are a myriad of ways to make your *own* application hang, deliberately or not.)

In response to your edit, I recall that [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) has the ability to manually suspend specific threads within a process. That would definitely be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "hang" and "not respond".  Any GUI app that stops processing messages will become unresponsive as far as the user is concerned.

Comment: unknown (google): a hook would do that if you need to stop only gui messages.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Sysinternals utility [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx)) has the ability both to suspend an entire process and to suspend an individual thread.  I have confirmed both features using Process Explorer v16.05.  I have found this useful for simulating failures of the nature described in the question.

This will work with any executable as is, but depending on the account under which the process is running, you may need administrative privileges in order to suspend the process or thread.

Answer (score 0):

while (true) {}

Comment: just an application, not the entire OS.

Comment: @Geo while (true) {} in a process will _not_ hang the entire OS, at least not Windows Vista.

Comment: When I replied there was no mention of a running process. And as Daniel already said, that will not hang the OS unless we're talking 16-bit windows or other non-multitasking OSes.

Answer (score 0):

an easy way would be set the priority of application you want to hang to minimum and then run a loop infinitely in your application at low priority. this would starve the other application. not perfect but simple

Answer (score 0):

If you could change code of that process so just insert `for(;;);` somewhere in it. If you could not change the code the easiest way to suspend process is using Process Explorer. Just right-click on wanted process and select Suspend in menu.

Comment: Thanks - process explorer was usefull, and it seems to do the trick.